# Maximizing inner product

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization

Suppose we have two row vectors $a$ and $b$ of nonnegative real numbers such that, for $j<k$ $a_j\leq a_k$ and $b_j\leq b_k$. Let P be a permutation matrix. Can we prove (or disprove) that 
$$ aPb^T \leq ab^T ?$$ 
Also, suppose we have two row vectors $a$ and $b$ of nonnegative real numbers. Let $ P_m$ be the cyclical permutation matrix that shifts by m. Is there any sort of closed form expression for the m that maximizes 
$$ a P_m b^T ?$$

Comment: For your first question, note that every permutation can be decomposed into a product of $2$-cycles.